# GNU Sed match first vertical bar and alter

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following data, tried all I could but didn't make it...

```
Las Vegas Nevada 89102|US|Katrina Roetteler
zhen fo shan guang dong 528318|CN|tu min jung
Zurich  CH8022|CH|Kevin M Pearl
Cheltenham GL52 8XX|UK|Kevin M Pearl
Melbourne Vic 3000|AU|brent chandler
Bratislava  821 03|Slovak Republic|SUSTRIK MARTIN MGR.
Zurich 8032|CH|David Graf
Tokyo 178-0063|JP|takahiro ichihashi
```

I need to alter it like this:

```
Las Vegas Nevada|89102|US|Katrina Roetteler
zhen fo shan guang dong|528318|CN|tu min jung
Zurich |CH8022|CH|Kevin M Pearl
Cheltenham|GL52 8XX|UK|Kevin M Pearl
Melbourne Vic|3000|AU|brent chandler
Bratislava |821 03|Slovak Republic|SUSTRIK MARTIN MGR.
Zurich|8032|CH|David Graf
Tokyo|178-0063|JP|takahiro ichihashi
```

basically to have the Zipcode/Postcode in another column (different types of postcodes for my clients all over the globe) and the Zipcode/Postcode is before first vertical bar.

Thanks!

Comment: Your probably going to have to use a separate regex for each country to match that country's postal codes

Comment: Your title and tags suggest that you want to use sed for this, as opposed to (say) AWK or Perl. Why is that? Do you have a sed script that's already partially working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/^\([A-Za-z ]*\) \([-A-Z 0-9]*|\)/\1|\2/' input
```

**Output**

```
Las Vegas Nevada|89102|US|Katrina Roetteler
zhen fo shan guang dong|528318|CN|tu min jung
Zurich |CH8022|CH|Kevin M Pearl
Cheltenham|GL52 8XX|UK|Kevin M Pearl
Melbourne Vic|3000|AU|brent chandler
Bratislava |821 03|Slovak Republic|SUSTRIK MARTIN MGR.
Zurich|8032|CH|David Graf
Tokyo|178-0063|JP|takahiro ichihashi
```

Answer (score 1):

The following regex does it:

```
sed 's/ \([A-Z]*[0-9][0-9]*\)/\|\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

Something to get you started using awk:

```
{
    for (i = 1; i < NF; i++) {
        if ($i~/\|/) {
            if ($(i-1)~/[0-9]/) {
                $(i-1) = "|"$(i-1)
            } else {
            $i = "|"$i
            }
            break
        }
    }
}
{print}
```

output:

```
Las Vegas Nevada |89102|US|Katrina Roetteler
zhen fo shan guang dong |528318|CN|tu min jung
Zurich |CH8022|CH|Kevin M Pearl
Cheltenham |GL52 8XX|UK|Kevin M Pearl
Melbourne Vic |3000|AU|brent chandler
Bratislava |821 03|Slovak Republic|SUSTRIK MARTIN MGR.
Zurich |8032|CH|David Graf
Tokyo |178-0063|JP|takahiro ichihashi
```